# two scan Events in one onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment, zxing

Ive got two Scan Events.
The First One, a QR Code Scan in my `MainActivity`
Code:

```
  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.scanbutton);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent,10);
            }
        });
```

And the secen one, a simple barcode scan in my `AddDataFragment`
Code:

```
        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_scan_serial);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A");
                startActivityForResult(intent,11);
            }
        });
```

This is my `onActivityResult`Code in my `MainActivity`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String scanContent = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String scanFormat = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Log.d("INHALT", scanContent);
                Log.d("FORMAT", scanFormat);

                switch (requestCode){
                    case (10):{
                        String[] Split = scanContent.split("\\s");
                        String product = Split[0];
                        String label = Split[1];
                        String serial = Split[2];
                        String mac = Split[3];
                        String daaid = Split[4];
                        String bill = Split[5];

                        mydb.insertData(product, label, serial, mac, daaid, bill);
                        break;
                    }
                    case (11):{
                        Log.d("TEST", "test test test - arrived here");
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                Log.d("TEST", "result_canceled");
                break;
            }

        Fragment fragment;
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragment = new ListViewFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

But if I scan an barcode the case switch didnt detect the `10`. after the scan zxing closes and the `ListViewFragment` pops up. Is there any mistake? And how do I push my `scanContent`string to my `AddDataFragment`?

Comment: If there are better ways and mine is completely wrong please feel free to say so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed **break;**

```
switch (requestCode){
        case (10):{
            String[] Split = scanContent.split("\\s");
            String product = Split[0];
            String label = Split[1];
            String serial = Split[2];
            String mac = Split[3];
            String daaid = Split[4];
            String bill = Split[5];

            mydb.insertData(product, label, serial, mac, daaid, bill);
            break;
        }
        case (11):{
            Log.d("TEST", "ICH HABE ERKANNT DAS ICH EINEN BARCODE GESCANNT HABE");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks dude your right. You solved a problem which wasnt one. (as yet)